# Read a file beginning with a specific line

Tags: java, iostream, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, fileinputstream

i Have this script and i want to extract lines from the line with HDK text to the line with SDK text  line per line

```
#! /bin/sh
# ==================================================================
#  ______                           __     _____
# /_  __/___  ____ ___  _________ _/ /_   /__  /
#  / / / __ \/ __ `__ \/ ___/ __ `/ __/     / /
# / / / /_/ / / / / / / /__/ /_/ / /_      / /
#/_/  \____/_/ /_/ /_/\___/\__,_/\__/     /_/

HDK 
# Multi-instance Apache Tomcat installation with a focus
# on best-practices as defined by Apache, SpringSource, and MuleSoft
# and enterprise use with large-scale deployments.
# Credits:
#       Google -> Couldn't survive without it
#       Stackoverflow.com -> Community support
#       SpringSource -> Specifically best-practices and seminars (Expert Series)
SDK 
# Based On:
#       http://www.springsource.com/files/uploads/tomcat/tomcatx-performance-tuning.pdf
http://www.springsource.com/files/u1/PerformanceTuningApacheTomcat-Part2.pdf
#       http://www.springsource.com/files/uploads/tomcat/tomcatx-large-scale-deployments.pdf
```

please help !
i did try

```
public class ScannerExample {

public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

    //creating File instance to reference text file in Java
    File text = new File("E:\\file.txt");

    //Creating Scanner instnace to read File in Java
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(text);

    //Reading each line of file using Scanner class
    int lineNumber = 1;
    int lineNumber1 = 1;
    int numinf = 1;
    int numsup=1;

    while(scnr.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scnr.nextLine();
        if (line.contains("HDK")){numinf=lineNumber;
        System.out.println(numinf);
  }

        if (line.contains("SDK")){numsup=lineNumber;
        System.out.println(numsup);}


        lineNumber++;
    }   
    Scanner scnr1 = new Scanner(text);

    while(scnr1.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scnr.nextLine();
        if (lineNumber>numinf){
        System.out.println("line " + lineNumber + " :" + line);}
        lineNumber1++;
    }       

  }   



  }
```

but it did not worked and i tied navigating the file with more than this methode and i could not limit the readnig in the wished area  !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly what is the eproblem you are facing.
But I can see a problem in your code

```
while(scnr1.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scnr.nextLine();//this line is a problem
        if (lineNumber>numinf){
        System.out.println("line " + lineNumber + " :" + line);}
        lineNumber1++;
    }
```

change scnr.nextLine() to scnr1.nextLine()
your code will get executed.

Comment: i want to begin the reading from the line number=numinf thats why i put line =scnr.nextline()

Comment: you have finished the reading from scnr reference, so when you try to read in the second scanner loop with scnr you will get exception with your code. So what I understood is you need a full solution.